# How do I scrape the live Enterprise Value/EBITDA & Book Value Per Share (mrq) from Yahoo Finance's Statistics page? (Google Sheets)

Tags: function, google-sheets, web-scraping, automation, google-sheets-formula

Using Google Sheets, I was able to learn how to scrape dividend and % yield of a stock from Yahoo Finance. I have been using Google Finance, Yahoo Finance, and Finviz for some data to automatically update my Sheet with stock data.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck with scraping "Enterprise Value/EBITDA" & "Book Value Per Share (mrq)" which can be found on the 'Statistics tab' of Yahoo Finance, when you search up a stock. I'm using Google Sheets where you can automate a result when you input a stock ticker (ie. AMD, AAPL, MSFT).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: for the sake of examples: I used this =GOOGLEFINANCE($C7, "marketcap") where $C7 dictates that I could drag down the box's formula to fit to the potentially endless list of stock tickers

Comment: Let me know if the data hereafter are the right ones (among more than 15.000 informations contained in the json)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the json that you can find in the source of the web page as follows

```
function yahooTest(ticker = 'AAPL') {
  const url = `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=${ticker}`;
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  console.log("ticker = " + ticker)
  console.log('trailingEnterprisesValueEBITDARatio = ' + data.context.dispatcher.stores.QuoteTimeSeriesStore.timeSeries.trailingEnterprisesValueEBITDARatio[0].reportedValue.raw)
  console.log('bookValue = ' + data.context.dispatcher.stores.QuoteSummaryStore.defaultKeyStatistics.bookValue.raw)
}
```

[image]

Comment: What line of the string should I be using? I'm not sure how I can use json specifically - though I've typically been able to right-click and 'Inspect' the specific number (under 'Current' and next to 'Enterprise Value/EBITDA', for example). I've been able to use IMPORTXML in the past - maybe you can post the specific Google Sheet formula that will give me the live result? This is the link you can use, ie. for AMD: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMD/key-statistics?p=AMD

Comment: in yahoo finance (nowadays) you usually can't use google native functions, yahoo embeds in the webpage a big json with almost 15,000+ information you can analyze

Comment: You can test here if the site is built by javascript on client side https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun

Comment: I've decided to try and use alternative sites. I'll look into these json thingies later - its just too complicated with no knowledge. Thanks for the information though!

Comment: I could never figure this out, there must be a simpler way...I'm too much of amateur for this. Could you guide me to a video tutorial?